# Error from egit installation

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github

Just installed a fresh 32 bit copy of Java and Eclipse. I'm now trying to add egit for the first time, following the instructions [here](http://eclipse.org/egit/download/) (using the main repository).

I receive this error when I try to install.

How do I overcome this?

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: EGit Mylyn 2.3.1.201302201838-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 2.3.1.201302201838-r)
>     Missing requirement: EGit Mylyn 2.3.1.201302201838-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 2.3.1.201302201838-r) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature.feature.group 3.5.0' but it could not be found

[image: Error]

Comment: Ran into same issue the other day. This answer applied for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050475/eclipse-error-when-installing-egit

Comment: Looks like you installing EGit Mylyn, but Mylyn's team feature is not installed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems more fit for Stack Overflow, where [it has already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050475/eclipse-error-when-installing-egit)

Answer (score 1):

Egit mylyn requires mylyn 3.5 or newer. It will work if you uncheck Egit mylyn. If you want to keep it, you need to enable the update sites for mylyn. If you check "contact all update sites..." in the Install New software dialog. The repo address if you want to manually add it is:
http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest